# How do I recreate the accesslog?

Tags: 8

In Drupal 7, every time a node is viewed the following columns are populated in the {accesslog} table:

- aid: unique accesslog ID
- sid: browser session ID of user that visited page
- title: title of page visited
- path: internal path to page visited (relative to Drupal root)
- url: referrer URI
- hostname: hostname of user that visited the page
- uid: user users.uid that visited the page
- timer: time in milliseconds that the page took to load
- timestamp: timestamp of when the page was visited

In Drupal 8, [the accesslog was removed from the statistics module](https://www.drupal.org/node/1446956). I would like to recreate some this functionality in a Drupal 8 custom module. I need:
- A hook to fire on every node view 
- Capture the relevant information
- Write it to a database table

My plan was to copy from statistics module, because it still counts node views. However, the code is not straight forward. In Drupal 8 the mechanism appears to be:

- Implement hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view(), which attaches some JavaScript and settings to the page build

  ```
  /**
   * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view() for node entities.
   */
  function statistics_node_view(array &$build, EntityInterface $node, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
    if (!$node->isNew() && $view_mode == 'full' && node_is_page($node) && empty($node->in_preview)) {
      $build['#attached']['library'][] = 'statistics/drupal.statistics';
      $settings = array('data' => array('nid' => $node->id()), 'url' => Url::fromUri('base:' . drupal_get_path('module', 'statistics') . '/statistics.php')->toString());
      $build['#attached']['drupalSettings']['statistics'] = $settings;
    }
  }
  ```
- Implement the following code in statistics.js

  ```
  /**
   * @file
   * Statistics functionality.
   */

  (function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {

    'use strict';

    $(document).ready(function () {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        url: drupalSettings.statistics.url,
        data: drupalSettings.statistics.data
      });
    });
  })(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
  ```
- Implement statistics.php, which where information gets written to the database

  ```
  /**
   * @file
   * Handles counts of node views via AJAX with minimal bootstrap.
   */

  use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
  use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

  chdir('../../..');
  $autoloader = require_once 'autoload.php';
  $kernel = DrupalKernel::createFromRequest(Request::createFromGlobals(), $autoloader, 'prod');
  $kernel->boot();
  $views = $kernel->getContainer()
    ->get('config.factory')
    ->get('statistics.settings')
    ->get('count_content_views');

  if ($views) {
    $nid = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nid', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    if ($nid) {
      \Drupal::database()->merge('node_counter')
        ->key('nid', $nid)
        ->fields(array(
          'daycount' => 1,
          'totalcount' => 1,
          'timestamp' => REQUEST_TIME,
        ))
        ->expression('daycount', 'daycount + 1')
        ->expression('totalcount', 'totalcount + 1')
        ->execute();
    }
  }
  ```

Can anyone explain this code?

Comment: how about using the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module to start from, and try to create a custom message type that includes the various columns from the accesslog table you mentioned?

Comment: Use event subscriber for response event and check if it is a entity.node.canonical route, if so get the node and write data into storage.

Comment: The answer to this question:https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/241653/hook-entity-type-view-only-fires-once-on-cache-rebuild, form @Berdir, suggests that `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view()` does not fire on every page view. Can this code then, taken from the core *Statistics* module, even work as a means of counting node views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official way to do your own thing in statistics.php, it is on purpose kept as light as possible.

But of course, you can duplicate its functionality and do whatever you want. The whole trick is adding a JS file that sends an uncached POST request to the server. That's the only reliable way to get access statistics for anonymous users, as those requests might be cached by the page cache or an external CDN/Varnish.

Given that you already posted all the relevant code, I'm not sure what you are asking exactly. You even linked to the d.o issue that removed that feature, which links to the change record (https://www.drupal.org/node/1900384), which in turn links to the contrib module that provides similar functionality: https://www.drupal.org/project/better_statistics. So instead of doing it yourself, you could build upon that.

Comment: I duplicated the code from the *Statistics* module, as above, into my own module, but I get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)` for my POST request. I have all three elements in place: the hook, the js file, and the php file. There is no obvious difference between my code and that of the *Statistics* module?

Comment: The issue, in the comment above, is to be found on line 149 of the root folder's .htaccess file.

Comment: @24ma13wg post your code on git repository so other developer and test and debug it.