# hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view() only fires once on cache rebuild?

Tags: 8, hooks

When implementing [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view/8.2.x) for nodes, I notice the following behaviour:

- Cache rebuild
- Navigate to node/1 // Message 'Node viewed!' displays
- Navigate to node/2 // Message 'Node viewed!' displays
- Navigate to node/1 // No message
- Navigate to node/2 // No message
- Cache rebuild
- Navigate to node/1 // Message 'Node viewed!' displays

My code:

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view() for node entities.
 */
function sitelog_node_view(array &$build, EntityInterface $node, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
    drupal_set_message(t('Test result: @result', array('@result' => 'Node viewed!')));
}
```

Is this the intended behaviour (it doesn't fire *every* time an entity is viewed) of hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view()?

Comment: On the basis of the answer [below](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/241661/1082) saying it is cached, then [Invalidate node cache so hook_node_view() runs on each node view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/222690/invalidate-node-cache-so-hook-node-view-runs-on-each-node-view) can help, I'd hope. I'm hoping it will for my case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. Entities are render cached. If your output is dynamic/depends on something, you need to provide the necessary cache contexts, use placeholders or something like that.

See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/cacheability-of-render-arrays.

If it's just about debugging locally, there is an example.settings.local.php file that has a example lines to disable those caches, but make sure you always test it with enabled caches before deploying.

Comment: Thanks. If this is the case, maybe you can shed some light on this question then: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/241626/how-do-i-recreate-the-accesslog.

Comment: But why isn't the message cached as well? Is there a more appropriate hook to implement, so that the message cached and displayed along with the node content?